# "hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to create a temp file"

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I came to work today and i found my hudson with this problem! I've tried to research, but i didn't found anything that help me.

Follow the full stack:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to create a temp file on /home/cpcaserver5/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace
    at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:966)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.createScriptFile(CommandInterpreter.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:68)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:60)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:175)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:137)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:429)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1366)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to create a temporary directory in /etc/tomcat6/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/temp
    at hudson.FilePath$12.invoke(FilePath.java:955)
    at hudson.FilePath$12.invoke(FilePath.java:944)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
    at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:944)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1716)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1804)
    at hudson.FilePath$12.invoke(FilePath.java:953)
    ... 16 more
Email was triggered for: Failure
Sending email for trigger: Failure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a permissions problem. Make sure you run Jenkins/Tomcat with appropriate user permissions. Ditto if this happens on a slave - check that slave process runs as a user that has appropriate permissions.